The error message won't show up in VScode powershell

How to turn on my VSCode PowerShell error message?
I get no error when I'm writing the PowerShell code, only the quote error show up but the language error won't show up.
Trying both download the error len and the  ctrl + shift + p  for Error squiggles it didn't work.
I was thinking I have to turn off the error message for PowerShell
other file was fine with error message and error lens but ps1 file and psm1 file didn't get any error message
I want the error message to show up when I write my PowerShell file.

and you do have the powershell extension installed right?
